# Subtract Numpy Array by Column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have an example array, say:

```
import numpy as np
np.array([[[ 85, 723]],
          [[ 86, 722]],
          [[ 87, 722]],
          [[ 89, 724]],
          [[ 88, 725]],
          [[ 87, 725]]])
```

What I want to do is subtract a number from only the second column, say `10` for example. What I hope to have the output look like is something like this:

```
np.array([[[ 85, 713]],
          [[ 86, 712]],
          [[ 87, 712]],
          [[ 89, 714]],
          [[ 88, 715]],
          [[ 87, 715]]])
```

I have tried using `np.subtract`, but it does not support subtraction along an axis (at least to my knowledge).

Comment: You seem to have a 3D array. Did you intend for it to be 3D? The length-1 dimension and the reference to "columns" suggests you might have intended to have something 2D.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slice and subtract -

```
a[...,1] -= 10
```

This would work for arrays of any number of dimensions to subtract from the second column.

Sample run -

```
In [582]: a
Out[582]: 
array([[[30, 23]],

       [[36, 88]],

       [[27, 15]],

       [[38, 61]],

       [[79, 14]]])

In [583]: a[...,1] -= 10

In [584]: a
Out[584]: 
array([[[30, 13]],

       [[36, 78]],

       [[27,  5]],

       [[38, 51]],

       [[79,  4]]])
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Do an in-place subtraction on the specified index (in this case I index the whole column):

```
>>> arr[:, :, 1] -= 10

>>> arr
array([[[ 85, 713]],
       [[ 86, 712]],
       [[ 87, 712]],
       [[ 89, 714]],
       [[ 88, 715]],
       [[ 87, 715]]])
```

Also works with [`np.subtract`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html) when you specify `out`:

```
>>> np.subtract(arr[:, :, 1], 10, out=arr[:, :, 1])
```